# How to fix a blank screen that comes from the use of Mapbox Bright?

Tags: python, folium

Please I have been trying to use the tile "Mapbox Bright" for a web map on python, but it keeps showing a blank screen. What do I do?

```
map = folium.Map(location=[7.156640, 4.527821], zoom_start=6)
map.save("Map1.html")

map = folium.Map(location=[7.156640, 4.527821], zoom_start=6,tiles="Mapbox Bright")
map.save("Map1.html")
```

Comment: High chances it's related to the need of an API key to use Mapbox tiles

Comment: docs are a good start. https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html However, I tried but with your specific tiles (Mapbox Bright), couldn't make it work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the Mapbox tiles are supposed to still work. See For a list of available tilesets see https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to obtain an API access token to make Mapbox tiles work.
Check it out [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/#retrieve-tiles) .

Alternatively, you can use the inbuilt tiles such as - ‘OpenStreetMap’, ‘Stamen Terrain’,‘Stamen Toner’,‘Stamen Watercolor’,‘cartodbpositron’, ‘cartodbdark_matter’.

Check out my blog if you want a [folium tutorial](https://www.nagarajbhat.com/post/folium-visualization/)

Comment: While your external links may contain information for answering this question, please consider making use of the space provided here to include more of that information. This is stackoverflow's preferred method.